# Program crashes when converting mxarray to cv::mat

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, mex

I'm trying to write a mex function to call another function F. F uses the opencv library, so I need to convert the mxarray into a cv::mat. I use a nested for loop to assign each pixel value or vector of values to the two created cv::mat. The code is posted below.

However, the program crashes after running the for-loop for a while. I tried to use mexPrintf to print out values such as A(i, j, 2) and the values are correct (unsigned char). The input from Matlab are matrices of type uint8, and this is the reason I cast things into unsigned char in the cpp code.

I have no idea why it is crashing. I also tried to use visual studio's attach process to debug, but it doesn't seem to work, and every time I attached the process and call the mex function in Matlab I just got a access violation message.

```
void mexFunction(int nlhs,mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs,const mxArray *prhs[])
{
#define A_IN prhs[0]
#define B_IN prhs[1]
#define Y_out plhs[0]
#define A(i,j,k) A[i+j*R+k*(R*C)]
#define B(i,j) B[i+j*R]
#define Y(i,j) Y[i+j*R]
const int *d_pr = mxGetDimensions(A_IN);
int C = d_pr[1];
int dims[2] = { R,C };
Y_out = mxCreateNumericArray(2, dims, mxUINT8_CLASS, mxREAL);
unsigned char *A, *B,*Y;
A = (unsigned char *)mxGetData(A_IN);
B = (unsigned char *)mxGetData(B_IN);
Y = (unsigned char *)mxGetData(Y_out);
cv::Mat image(R, C, CV_8UC3);
cv::Mat trimap(R, C, CV_8UC1);
for (int i = 0; i < R; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < C; j++) {
        image.at<cv::Vec3b>(j, i)[0] = A(i, j, 2);
        image.at<cv::Vec3b>(j, i)[1] = A(i, j, 1);
        image.at<cv::Vec3b>(j, i)[2] = A(i, j, 0);
        trimap.at<unsigned char>(j,i) =  B(i, j);
    }
}  


//some other stuff
```

}

Comment: Have you looked at the call stack to know the line of code that is causing the crash?

Comment: @VadaPoché I'm not able to use visual studio's attach process to debug it. Will I still be able to check the call stack?

Comment: Do you have debugging information (pdb) generate for this other process that you want to debug? If so, are you able to check if the debugger is able to locate it?

Comment: @VadaPoché I see. I forgot to turn on enable debugging when compiling the mex file. I'm now able to attach the process and debug using visual studio.

Comment: @VadaPoché I ran the code twice. For both time the program break at this line:  image.at<cv::Vec3b>(j, i)[2] = A(i, j, 0);, but at different (i,j)

Comment: If I check the value of image. I see (image).data  0x00000000ff8fd840  <Invalid characters in string.> Not sure why.

Comment: Now that you've a callstack, I'd recommend that you work your way back from the point of crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the 4 lines of code inside the for-loop:

```
image.at<cv::Vec3b>(j, i)[0] = A(i, j, 2);
image.at<cv::Vec3b>(j, i)[1] = A(i, j, 1);
image.at<cv::Vec3b>(j, i)[2] = A(i, j, 0);
trimap.at<unsigned char>(j,i) =  B(i, j);
```

into:

```
image.row(i).col(j).data[0] = A(i, j, 2);
image.row(i).col(j).data[1] = A(i, j, 1);
image.row(i).col(j).data[2] = A(i, j, 0);
trimap.row(i).col(j).data[0] = B(i, j);
```

works for me.

Comment: But I don't know why.